# LINQ - check for equality inside join

Tags: c#, linq, join

Is it possible to check if in LINQ Join method first object (not)equals the second object?

For example,

Let say I implemented SomeData class with Name and Number property. I made three different instances of this class and stored them inside List<> object.

```
List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
SomeData a = new SomeData();
SomeData p = new SomeData();
SomeData v = new SomeData();

a.Name = "Ann";
a.Number = 1;
p.Name = "Peter";
p.Number = 4;
v.Name = "Vicky";
v.Number = 1;

data.Add(a);
data.Add(p);
data.Add(v);
```

Now, I'd like to get new SomeData object which is created with two SomeData instances in data List have the same Number property.

```
var joinedData = data
.Join(first => first.Number,
     second => second.Number,
     (first, second) => new SomeData
     {
         Name = first.Name + " & " + second.Name,
         Number = first.Number
      });
```

However, when this query executes, it creates object even when first and second are the very same instaces. Is there a way to check for this inside query? Something like

```
var joinedData = data
.Join(first => first.Number,
      second => second.Number,
      if (first != second)
      {
          (first, second) => new SomeData
          {
          ...
          }
      });
```

Only thing I'd really like is that I get answer in "non-SQL like syntax".

EDIT1:
Current output with code

```
foreach(SomeData sd in joinedData)
{
 Console.Writeline (sd.Name)
}
```

is

```
Peter & Peter
Vicky & Vicky
Vicky & Ann
Ann & Vicky
Ann & Ann
```

and desired output is

```
Ann & Vicky
```

Right, actually above would be perfect-desired output, however,

```
Ann & Vicky
Vicky & Ann
```

will do just fine.

Comment: Could you please supply the desired output for the sample data that you showed?

Comment: "non-SQL like syntax" = Lambda

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Even if you removed entries where the names were equal, you'd still get one for "Ann & Vicky" and another for "Vicky & Ann".

Comment: @BenAaronson I'm not trying to compare Names (property of an object), but objects themselves - e.g. if(v != s), and not if(v.Name != s.Name)

Answer (score 1):

Join does that per default (ie use a default comparer with x.Equals(y))

If you need a custom comparison you can use the overload where you give an IEqualityComparer (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549267(v=vs.90).ASPX))

```
var myComparer = new MyComparer();  //Must implement IEqualityComparer<T>
var joinedData = data.Join(other, first => first.Number, second => second.Number, (first, second) => {...}, myComparer);
```